# "Colourizing" a Bitmap in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, image-manipulation, system.drawing

If you have a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` instance that contains a greyscale image, is there a built in way to "colourize" it with the influence of another colour?

For example, if you had a black and white (greyscale) picture of a coffee mug and you wanted to create separate images of red, green and purple versions programmatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have a code example to give but here's a way to do this. Convert each pixel from RGB to HSV and change the Hue and Saturation component on each pixel. The Hue controls the Color. The Value should stay the same. The result will be a Bitmap with the same lightness and darkness but with a different color.

Edit: here's an example. Notice the Hue and Saturation update.

```
        public static Color ColorFromAhsb(int a, float h, float s, float b)
    {

        if (0 > a || 255 < a)
        {
            throw new Exception("a");
        }
        if (0f > h || 360f < h)
        {
            throw new Exception("h");
        }
        if (0f > s || 1f < s)
        {
            throw new Exception("s");
        }
        if (0f > b || 1f < b)
        {
            throw new Exception("b");
        }

        if (0 == s)
        {
            return Color.FromArgb(a, Convert.ToInt32(b * 255),
              Convert.ToInt32(b * 255), Convert.ToInt32(b * 255));
        }

        float fMax, fMid, fMin;
        int iSextant, iMax, iMid, iMin;

        if (0.5 < b)
        {
            fMax = b - (b * s) + s;
            fMin = b + (b * s) - s;
        }
        else
        {
            fMax = b + (b * s);
            fMin = b - (b * s);
        }

        iSextant = (int)Math.Floor(h / 60f);
        if (300f <= h)
        {
            h -= 360f;
        }
        h /= 60f;
        h -= 2f * (float)Math.Floor(((iSextant + 1f) % 6f) / 2f);
        if (0 == iSextant % 2)
        {
            fMid = h * (fMax - fMin) + fMin;
        }
        else
        {
            fMid = fMin - h * (fMax - fMin);
        }

        iMax = Convert.ToInt32(fMax * 255);
        iMid = Convert.ToInt32(fMid * 255);
        iMin = Convert.ToInt32(fMin * 255);

        switch (iSextant)
        {
            case 1:
                return Color.FromArgb(a, iMid, iMax, iMin);
            case 2:
                return Color.FromArgb(a, iMin, iMax, iMid);
            case 3:
                return Color.FromArgb(a, iMin, iMid, iMax);
            case 4:
                return Color.FromArgb(a, iMid, iMin, iMax);
            case 5:
                return Color.FromArgb(a, iMax, iMin, iMid);
            default:
                return Color.FromArgb(a, iMax, iMid, iMin);
        }

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap("c:\\bw.bmp");

        foreach (int y in Enumerable.Range(0, bmp.Height))
        { 
            foreach (int x in Enumerable.Range(0,bmp.Width))
            {
                var p = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
                var h = p.GetHue();

                var c = ColorFromAhsb(p.A, p.GetHue() + 200, p.GetSaturation() + 0.5f, p.GetBrightness());
                bmp.SetPixel(x, y, c);                    
            }
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
        //bmp.Dispose();

    }
```

Comment: Thank you. That works great modified slightly. What's the significance of "p.GetSaturation() + 0.5f"? The 0.5 seems to mess things up if the "colourizing" colour is itself a shade of grey (output is reddish), but be required otherwise.

Comment: @frou - In the bitmap that I was using the Saturation was 0. If the Saturation is zero, modifying the Hue does not change the color. I just added an arbitrary 0.5 to the zero value. Saturation should be any value greater than zero and less than or equal to 1.

Answer (score 2):

If it's an 8 bit image, you can just use a different the palette (Image.Palette). That's essentially a lookup table that assigns a Color value to each possible pixel byte value. Much faster than changing all pixels in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a copy of the original image and them put a separate semi transparent image of the desired color of the top.

**Update:** see example at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Merge_Images_in_C_.aspx

Comment: How do you do that? You would have to specify a "modulate" rather than additive type of layer blending, right?

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/922913/1064190.aspx#1064190)

I have used this in the past. You are wanting to look specifically at ToSepia.
You may need to deconstruct this a bit but it has worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure of a built in way but, if you represent each colour as a float rather than a byte (255 becomes 1 - full intensity), multiplying the each channel with your desired colour should give the effect you are talking about.

```
(1,1,1) "white" * (1,0,0) "red" = (1,0,0) "red"

(0.5,0.5, 0.5) "grey" * (0,1,0) "green" = (0,0.5,0) "dark green"
```

You do need to apply this per pixel though.

Comment: Thanks. The "HSV" approach gives nicer looking results for me - I don't fully understand why :)